# Loader- Is it a generic system program?

Tags: assembly, compilation, system, bootloader, bootstrapping

The standard model of program execution tells us that a compiler/assembler compiles/assembles source program and produces object code.This object program is brought into memory by object program loader.Is there a object program loader preconfigured in every system or does it come bundled with compiler/assembler?How is a object program loader different from boot loader?Where is object program loader stored?(Bootloader is stored in ROM).How is object program loader itself brought into memory?

Answer (score 0):

Object program loader is part of OS. It knows how and where to read the object code. Otherwise there would be no way to load the loader itself.
Boot loader only knows how to load the boot and how to find the boot code from a disk (or some other boot medium). When boot loader runs, there is no file system handlers in the memory - they are OS specific.